# Is there any relation between WCF and HttpWebRequest

Tags: wcf, httpwebrequest, webclient

What is the specialty of WCF? Does WCF have any relation to `HttpWebRequest`, `WebClient`, etc? What is the main functionality of WCF?

If there is a relationship between WCF and `HttpWebRequest`, how can I use them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF is meant for designing and deploying distributed applications under service-oriented architecture (SOA) implementation.
WCF is designed using service oriented architecture principles to support distributed computing where services have remote consumers. Clients can consume multiple services; services can be consumed by multiple clients. Services are loosely coupled to each other. Services typically have a WSDL interface (Web Services Description Language) that any WCF client can use to consume the service, regardless of which platform the service is hosted on. WCF implements many advanced Web services (WS) standards such as WS-Addressing, WS-Reliable Messaging and WS-Security. With the release of .NET Framework 4.0, WCF also provides RSS Syndication Services, WS-Discovery, routing and better support for REST services.

Answer (score 1):

**WCF** is **Windows Communication Foundation**. It is a framework for composing data-driven services. These could be web services, but they don't have to be.

You're probably best off reading this:

- [Windows Communication Foundation is...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324)

Comment: does this wcf and HttpWebrequest having any relation in b/W ??? I am new to this technologies thats y i am asking?

Comment: WCF is a **framework**. So they are related in that WCF *can be* web-enabled and *may* use `HttpWebRequest`. In what way do you see them being "related"?